# How to resize a WebGlBuffer?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm working on some WebGL code, and a part of it is dealing with instances of [`WebGlBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WebGLBuffer) to hold vertex attributes.

I don't know (a priori) the amount of data the buffers will have to hold, so the `WebGlBuffer` will be growing as more triangles are added to the scene, something like:

```
/// Init the WebGlBuffer
var buff = gl.createBuffer();

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buff);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 1024, this._gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

/// Push data for some triangles
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,   0, new Float32Array( dataForVertex0 ));
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 128, new Float32Array( dataForVertex1 ));
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 256, new Float32Array( dataForVertex2 ));


/// A few seconds later, room for more triangles is needed

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buff);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 2048, this._gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

/// ... so I can keep adding data for more triangles
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 1024, new Float32Array( dataForVertex0 ));
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 1152, new Float32Array( dataForVertex1 ));
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 1280, new Float32Array( dataForVertex2 ));
```

My problem is that every call to [`gl.bufferData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/bufferData) will overwrite the current contents of the `WebGlBuffer` with zeroes. `bufferSubData` will not resize the buffer automatically, triggering buffer overflow warnings instead.

As far as I'm aware, the only ways to manipulate the contents of a `WebGlBuffer` are `bufferData` and `bufferSubData`.

For performance reasons, I'd like to avoid keeping an `ArrayBuffer` with a copy of the data (as the buffers will use a non-trivial amount of memory).

Is there any way to (efficiently) resize an instance of `WebGlBuffer`, or to copy the contents of a smaller `WebGlBuffer` into a bigger `WebGlBuffer`? Am I missing any feature of the WebGL API, or must I go back to keeping duplicate data?

Comment: What about make buffer larger from start? Could it help?

Comment: As I said: «I don't know (a priori) the amount of data the buffers will have to hold». Might be 3KiB, might be 500MiB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately, WebGL lacks such abilities. If you want to resize a buffer, you'll lose it's content, there's no way around that. All you can do is try to allocate enough space for all future uses beforehand. In my project I do that and also keep copy of buffer content for possible "out of memory" situation (it also helps with batching buffer updates). But my geometry data is relatively small.

Also WebGL2 has [`copyBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#3.7.3) call just for that.

Comment: Then I'll go back to keep a copy in an `ArrayBuffer`. Thanks for confirming my suspicions.